# How to manipulate a page with React Native WebView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I used `react-native-webview` to open the webpage, but the audio doesn't automatically stream/play until I press the button. Is there a way I can open the page and have it directly play or can I add a custom  that plays the radio/audio on click?

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'

export default function Test() {
    const jsCode = "setTimeout(function() { const playButton = document.getElementsByClassName('jp-play')[0]; playButton.click();}, 2000)";

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <WebView
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
                source={{ uri: 'https://duckduckgo.com/?q=google&ia=web' }}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a javascript code into the `WebView` component to achieve that.

First, you need to **wait** some seconds for loading the web view, then get the play button element by its id/className or any query selector you want.

since your play button has a `jp-play` className, you can use it to select this play button and then click on it:

let's implement:

```
const jsCode = "setTimeout(function() { const playButton = document.getElementsByClassName('jp-play')[0]; playButton.click();}, 2000)";


<WebViw 
  source={{ uri: 'https://mmufmkenya.radio12345.com/' }}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}    // ---> don't forget this
  injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
/>
```

Comment: try this alternative library https://github.com/iou90/react-native-autoheight-webview @999sang

Comment: Has the same results with webview @nima